# Update command for data table in C# not working

Tags: c#, database

I am relatively new to the world of databases and C# and I am having a problem getting my data tables to update according to changes I make via a C# program. I am using a TableAdapter to issue commands to the database.

In my program I have a form that allows a new row to be added to the data table. As far as I can tell this works, because the rest of my program can access the new information by querying the database.

```
    this.patientInfoTableTableAdapter.InsertNewPatient(
                this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.StreetAddress, this.City, this.State, this.Zip,
                this.Email, this.Phone, this.DOB, this.Gender);
```

I can even stop the run of the program and restart it, and the added data is still accessible. However, when I view the data table directly, the added row is not there and the next time I run the program the table has reverted to the unmodified state in the program's eyes as well.

I do have an Update method that I use every time I go through this process, but it has no effect, either on retaining the added row or any changes to the existing rows:

```
    this.Validate();
    this.patientInfoTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.eMRSDatabaseDataSet);
    MessageBox.Show("Update Successful");
```

I always see the MessageBox appear and I do not get any errors.

I have come to the conclusion that some setting or property for my database is amiss, and I could use some help figuring out my problem.

In case it helps, the database queries for the involved code follow:

```
    INSERT INTO [PatientInfoTable] ([First_Name], [Last_Name], [Street_Address], [City], [State], [Zip], [Email], [Phone], [DOB], [Gender]) VALUES (@fName, @lName, @sAddress, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @phone, @dob, @gender)
```

and

```
    UPDATE       PatientInfoTable
    SET                Street_Address = @saddress, City = @city, State = @state, Zip = @zip, Email = @email, Phone = @phone, Gender = @gender
    WHERE        (Patient_ID = @p11)
```

These queries were generated using the Visual Studio query builder.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

```
query = "Update mcm_class Set class_status='" + 
dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString() + "' where class_id ='" + 
dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].ToString() + "'"+ "AND"+" med_id='" + 
lst_med.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Downvoted due to (mainly) not using [parameters](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/02/18/Why-Parameters-are-a-Best-Practice.aspx) but string concatenation, that is an unfortunately frequent bad-practise that may lead you to serious problems in the real-life.